# Как правильно составить выражение XPath, чтобы исключить дочерний тег в файле xml?

Tags: xml, xpath

Как правильно составить выражение Xpath, чтобы убрать вложенный узел <ds:Signature> ?

Исходный XML:

```
<org:exportOrgRegistryRequest>
    <ds:Signature>
        <!-- вложенные узлы -->
    </ds:Signature> 
    <org:SearchCriteria>
        <!-- вложенные узлы -->
    </org:SearchCriteria>
</org:exportOrgRegistryRequest>
```

Необходимый XML:

```
<org:exportOrgRegistryRequest>
    <org:SearchCriteria>
        <!-- вложенные узлы -->
    </org:SearchCriteria>
</org:exportOrgRegistryRequest>
```

Пробовал XPath: `(//. | //@* | //namespace::*)[self::org:exportOrgRegistryRequest]/*[not(self::ds:Signature)]`

Но возвращается только тэг `<org:SearchCriteria>` без родительского `<org:exportOrgRegistryRequest>`

Пример полного xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:base="http://dom.gosuslugi.ru/schema/integration/base/" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:org="http://dom.gosuslugi.ru/schema/integration/organizations-registry-common/" xmlns:org1="http://dom.gosuslugi.ru/schema/integration/organizations-registry-base/" xmlns:org2="http://dom.gosuslugi.ru/schema/integration/organizations-registry-base/" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Header>
        <base:ISRequestHeader xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <base:Date>2023-10-19T08:58:51</base:Date>
            <base:MessageGUID>1fe9a850-5826-49db-9651-f5b5aa2efaa5</base:MessageGUID>
        </base:ISRequestHeader>
    </soapenv:Header>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <org:exportOrgRegistryRequest xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" Id="body" base:version="10.0.2.1">
            <ds:Signature Id="xmldsig-a94c7f7d-5d13-43b4-99bb-4437787fac2d">
                <ds:SignedInfo>
                    <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
                    <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:cpxmlsec:algorithms:gostr34102012-gostr34112012-256"/>
                    <ds:Reference URI="#body">
                        <ds:Transforms>
                            <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/>
                            <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
                        </ds:Transforms>
                        <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:cpxmlsec:algorithms:gostr34112012-256"/>
                        <ds:DigestValue>123</ds:DigestValue>
                    </ds:Reference>
                </ds:SignedInfo>
                <ds:SignatureValue>123</ds:SignatureValue>
                <ds:KeyInfo Id="xmldsig-a381c745-b7bc-44bd-bb6f-ee5a42b53eef">
                    <ds:X509Data>
                        <ds:X509Certificate>123</ds:X509Certificate>
                    </ds:X509Data>
                </ds:KeyInfo>
            </ds:Signature>
            <org:SearchCriteria>
                <OGRN xmlns="http://dom.gosuslugi.ru/schema/integration/organizations-base/">1025002738738</OGRN>
            </org:SearchCriteria>
        </org:exportOrgRegistryRequest>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: (1) Ваш XML должен иметь объявления пространства имен XML. (2) Вам нужно использовать XQuery или XSLT, чтобы получить то, что вам нужно. XPath не может делать то, что вам нужно.

Comment: В полном файле объявления пространства имен есть. В вопросе описал только ключевые узлы xml, чтобы не публиковать полный текст xml

Comment: Полный текст xml добавил к вопросу

Comment: Как справедливо отметил Ицхак, нужно использовать другой язык/технологию. XPath - язык _запросов_. Он только для _получения_ данных, а не для их _изменения_. С его помощью можно получить либо `exportOrgRegistryRequest` со всеми вложенными узлами, либо только `SearchCriteria` без родительского. А далее либо удалить лишнее из родительского узла, либо добавить родительский узел с помощью языка общего назначения (что вы там используете: Java, PHP, Python, etc).

Comment: Я добавил к ответу решение с XSLT.

Answer (score 0):

**Входной XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:base="http://dom.gosuslugi.ru/schema/integration/base/"
                  xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"
                  xmlns:org="http://dom.gosuslugi.ru/schema/integration/organizations-registry-common/"
                  xmlns:org1="http://dom.gosuslugi.ru/schema/integration/organizations-registry-base/"
                  xmlns:org2="http://dom.gosuslugi.ru/schema/integration/organizations-registry-base/"
                  xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Header>
        <base:ISRequestHeader xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <base:Date>2023-10-19T08:58:51</base:Date>
            <base:MessageGUID>1fe9a850-5826-49db-9651-f5b5aa2efaa5</base:MessageGUID>
        </base:ISRequestHeader>
    </soapenv:Header>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <org:exportOrgRegistryRequest xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                                      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                                      Id="body" base:version="10.0.2.1">
            <ds:Signature Id="xmldsig-a94c7f7d-5d13-43b4-99bb-4437787fac2d">
                <ds:SignedInfo>
                    <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
                    <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:cpxmlsec:algorithms:gostr34102012-gostr34112012-256"/>
                    <ds:Reference URI="#body">
                        <ds:Transforms>
                            <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/>
                            <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
                        </ds:Transforms>
                        <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:cpxmlsec:algorithms:gostr34112012-256"/>
                        <ds:DigestValue>123</ds:DigestValue>
                    </ds:Reference>
                </ds:SignedInfo>
                <ds:SignatureValue>123</ds:SignatureValue>
                <ds:KeyInfo Id="xmldsig-a381c745-b7bc-44bd-bb6f-ee5a42b53eef">
                    <ds:X509Data>
                        <ds:X509Certificate>123</ds:X509Certificate>
                    </ds:X509Data>
                </ds:KeyInfo>
            </ds:Signature>
            <org:SearchCriteria>
                <OGRN xmlns="http://dom.gosuslugi.ru/schema/integration/organizations-base/">1025002738738</OGRN>
            </org:SearchCriteria>
        </org:exportOrgRegistryRequest>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

**XPath**

```
/soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body/org:exportOrgRegistryRequest/org:SearchCriteria
```

**Результат**

```
<org:SearchCriteria>
    <OGRN xmlns="http://dom.gosuslugi.ru/schema/integration/organizations-base/">1025002738738</OGRN>
</org:SearchCriteria>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:base="http://dom.gosuslugi.ru/schema/integration/base/"
                xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"
                xmlns:org="http://dom.gosuslugi.ru/schema/integration/organizations-registry-common/"
                xmlns:org1="http://dom.gosuslugi.ru/schema/integration/organizations-registry-base/"
                xmlns:org2="http://dom.gosuslugi.ru/schema/integration/organizations-registry-base/"
                xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"
                omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <!--Identity transform-->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!--Remove ds:Signature-->
    <xsl:template match="ds:Signature"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Результат**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:org2="http://dom.gosuslugi.ru/schema/integration/organizations-registry-base/"
                  xmlns:org1="http://dom.gosuslugi.ru/schema/integration/organizations-registry-base/"
                  xmlns:base="http://dom.gosuslugi.ru/schema/integration/base/"
                  xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
                  xmlns:org="http://dom.gosuslugi.ru/schema/integration/organizations-registry-common/"
                  xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
    <soapenv:Header>
        <base:ISRequestHeader xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                              xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
            <base:Date>2023-10-19T08:58:51</base:Date>
            <base:MessageGUID>1fe9a850-5826-49db-9651-f5b5aa2efaa5</base:MessageGUID>
        </base:ISRequestHeader>
    </soapenv:Header>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <org:exportOrgRegistryRequest base:version="10.0.2.1"
                                      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                                      Id="body"
                                      xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
            <org:SearchCriteria>
                <OGRN xmlns="http://dom.gosuslugi.ru/schema/integration/organizations-base/">1025002738738</OGRN>
            </org:SearchCriteria>
        </org:exportOrgRegistryRequest>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: Как на прямую к тэгу обратиться понимаю, а вот как из родительского узла "org:exportOrgRegistryRequest" удалить дочерний узел "ds:Signature", а другие дочерние узлы оставить нет

Comment: Вам нужно использовать XQuery или XSLT, чтобы получить то, что вам нужно. XPath не может удалить дочерний узел "ds:Signature".